# Why ElasticSearch is not finding my term

Tags: elasticsearch

I just installed and testing elastic search it looks great and i need to know some thing i have an configuration file

`elasticsearch.json` in `config` directory

```
{    
"network" : {
    "host" : "127.0.0.1"
},
"index" : {
    "number_of_shards": 3,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "refresh_interval" : "2s",        
    "analysis" : {
        "analyzer" : {                
            "index_analyzer" : {                    
                "tokenizer" : "nGram",
                "filter" : ["lowercase"]
            },
            "search_analyzer" : {                                                    
                "tokenizer" : "nGram",
                "filter" : ["lowercase"]
            }
        },                               
        "// you'll need lucene dep for this: filter" : {                
            "snowball": {
                "type" : "snowball",
                "language" : "English"
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

and i have inserted an doc that contains a word `searching` if i search for keyword
 `search` it says nothing found...

wont it stem before indexing or i missed some thing in config ....

Comment: Hpow are you doing the search?  What does the doc look like?

Comment: `$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1 -d '{
    "user": "kimchy",
    "post_date": "2009-11-15T13:12:00",
    "message": "Trying out searching teaching, so far so good?"
}'`
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?q=message:search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How looks your query?

your config does not look good. try:

```
 ...
"index_analyzer" : {                    
   "tokenizer" : "nGram",
   "filter" : ["lowercase", "snowball"]
},
 "search_analyzer" : {                                                    
    "tokenizer" : "nGram",
    "filter" : ["lowercase", "snowball"]
}
},
"filter" : {
                "snowball": {
                    "type" : "snowball",
                    "language" : "English"
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble overriding the "default_search" and "default_index" analyzer as well.

This works though. 
You can add "index_analyzer" to default all string fields with unspecified analyzers within a type, if need be.

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/twitter

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/twitter -d '
{"index": 
  { "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
       "filter": {
                "snowball": {
                    "type" : "snowball",
                    "language" : "English"
                }
                 },
       "analyzer": { "a2" : {
                    "type":"custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "snowball"]
                    }
                  }
     }
  }
}
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_mapping -d '{
    "tweet" : {
        "date_formats" : ["yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy"],
        "properties" : {
            "user": {"type":"string"},
            "message" : {"type" : "string", "analyzer":"a2"}
        }
    }}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1 -d '{ "user": "kimchy", "post_date": "2009-11-15T13:12:00", "message": "Trying out searching teaching, so far so good?" }'

curl -XGET localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?q=message:search 

curl -XGET localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?q=message:try
```