# ElasticSearch and Porterstem analyser

Tags: elasticsearch, porter-stemmer

I'm looking at using Elasticsearch to provide the search functions of our site.

I've been experimenting with it but am unable to enable the Porterstem analyser (so that a search for fight matches fights and fighting).

Here's a run down of my input.

```
    curl -XPUT localhost:9200/local/ -d'
    index :                     
        analysis : 
            analyzer : 
                stemming : 
                    type : custom 
                    tokenizer : standard 
                    filter : [standard, lowercase, stop, porterStem] 
    '

    curl -XPUT localhost:9200/local/_mapping -d'{"properties": { "title" : { "analyzer" : "stemming", "type" : "string" }}}'

    curl -XPUT localhost:9200/local/article/1 -d'{"title": "Fight for your life"}'
    curl -XPUT localhost:9200/local/article/2 -d'{"title": "Fighting for your life"}'
    curl -XPUT localhost:9200/local/article/3 -d'{"title": "My dad fought a dog"}'
    curl -XPUT localhost:9200/local/article/4 -d'{"title": "Bruno fights Tyson tomorrow"}'
```

However running a search for 'fight' only matches the first entry - the one that contains the exact term.

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/local/_search?q=fight
```

The correct settings appear to have been set up but doesn't seem to work.

```
      "indices" : {
        "local" : {
          "aliases" : [ ],
          "settings" : {
            "index.analysis.analyzer.stemming.type" : "custom",
            "index.analysis.analyzer.stemming.tokenizer" : "standard",
            "index.analysis.analyzer.stemming.filter.1" : "lowercase",
            "index.analysis.analyzer.stemming.filter.0" : "standard",
            "index.analysis.analyzer.stemming.filter.3" : "porterStem",
            "index.analysis.analyzer.stemming.filter.2" : "stop",
            "index.number_of_shards" : "5",
            "index.number_of_replicas" : "1"
          },
```

Anyone got this functionality up and running and able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example config on using custom analyzers, using the snowball stemmer: 
[Why ElasticSearch is not finding my term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981001/why-elasticsearch-is-not-finding-my-term)