# ElasticSearch query failing due to state codes "in" and "or" being reserved words

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm querying for states using the state code as the query string, and "in" and "or" (Indiana and Oregon) are failing, presumably because they're reserved words.

I can confirm that the data exists in the index correctly, because when I run:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/state/_search?size=200&pretty=true' -d '{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}}' > out.txt
```

I can see the data there for both the working states and the non-working states. Plus, if I change the state code of a non-working state in CouchDB to something like XYZ, I can verify that the change makes it to ES by running the above command and searching for XYZ. So I know I'm looking at the right data and it's indexing fine.

The problem is the query. Right now, here's what my entire query object looks like:

```
var q = {
     size: 0,
     query: {
         filtered: {
             query: { term: { postcode: 'tn' } },
             filter: { term: { version: 2 } }
         }
     },
     facets: {
         version: {  terms: { field: "version" }  },
         count : { statistical : { field : "latestValues.enroll"  } }
     }
};
```

If I run that query, I get no results. If I change the "or" out with "tn" or "tx" or "sc" etc., then it works fine.

I looked for a way to escape reserved words and found [this link](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Searching-for-a-reserved-word-OR-td2238889.html) but it doesn't seem to work for me, when running the following query:

```
var q = {
    size: 0,
    query: {
        filtered: {
            query: { match_all: { } },
            filter: { term: { version: 2, postcode: 'or' } }
        }
    },
    facets: {
        version: {  terms: { field: "version" }  },
        count : { statistical : { field : "latestValues.enroll"  } }
    }
};
```

(Note that that query also works when changing out "or" with a non-reserved-word-state so I know it's not a problem with the query itself).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not about "reserved" words, its about stop words. You are using an analyzer which removes stop words (the default analyzer up to a more recent version of Elasticsearch).

You'll need to change the analyzer for the field, see here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html

This will change require reindexing, though

Comment: Do you happen to have any more info on changing the analyzer anywhere? I'm having trouble googling a good example. Also, is this a server-level config change, meaning it goes in /etc/elasticseach/elasticsearch.yml?

Comment: it is also possible to set it up in code, see https://github.com/synhershko/WikipediaSearchDemo/blob/master/wikipedia-indexer/src/main/java/com/code972/ir/App.java#L54 for example. You might want to send an empty list of stopwords with it like explained here http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-snowball-analyzer.html

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981001/why-elasticsearch-is-not-finding-my-term

Comment: http://vanwilgenburg.wordpress.com/2013/08/03/diacritics-in-elasticsearch/ is an article I wrote which might help. It shows you how to add an analyzer via rest calls. Remember to change both the index analyzer and search analyzer.